# Doing an "offline" erlang OTP release upgrade

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I'm working on a project that deals heavily with OTP releases and their upgrade process.
I managed to perform hot upgrades from a release upgrade archive (tar.gz) using release_handler functions unpack_release, install_release and make_permanent. They are all invoked in the very node that is being upgraded.

Now I have to deal with a situation where the erlang node is down and I have to do an "offline" upgrade. Essentially what I want to achieve is to unpack release, and update certain files like RELEASES and start_erl.data (maybe some more?) so they are in the same state as they would be after a hot upgrade. The result would be that when the node is started, newly installed erlang release is booted. Also, an important thing is that I want to avoid running old release.

Any ideas how to do this as simple and cleanly as possible?

Comment: having node down is great chance to deploy code from scratch. What about that? Leave Mnesia dir etc. but substitute whole build/release structure. What you think about that?

Comment: Yes, creating the whole structure from the scratch is a viable solution, but there's one problem with that: I will have to gerenerate `RELEASES` file and the function responsible for that (`release_handler:create_RELEASES`) only lists a single given release and it completely forgets about old releases. I would like to avoid that loss of information, because I want to use it to remove old releases using the `release_handler`. Or maybe you think I should try to do the cleanup manually, too?

Comment: yeah, lets think.. the real advantage you get from all the info in releases is possibility of roll back. The offline node - it is going to be the first one with the new code or the last one? Also, how you connect nodes? Can you put it up and do not join to a cluster?

Comment: Well, the system is actually not distributed. All what I wrote about deals with a single erlang target system, that I called a "node", because it is an "embedded node" as rebar generates it (`rebar create-node`).

Answer (score 2):

Start an erlang node to get a shell.  There is no need for a node name just be sure you are running the same `~/bin/erl` that the target node does.  Then place your release package in `~/lib/erlang/releases` and unpack as you would normally:

```
1> application:start(sasl),
1> release_handler:unpack_release("my_release-1.0").
{ok, "1.0"}.
```

Now quit, shutting down the shell:

```
2> q().
```

[Don't try and cheat by using another window here!  You must quit.]

Now you need to edit the `~/lib/erlang/releases/RELEASES` file and change the status of the new release from `unpacked` to `current`:

```
[{release,"My Release Package","1.0","5.9.1",
       [{kernel,"2.15.1","/Users/otpuser/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-2.15.1"},
        {stdlib,"1.18.1","/Users/otpuser/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-1.18.1"},
        {sasl,"2.2.1","/Users/otpuser/lib/erlang/lib/sasl-2.2.1"}, ...],
-     unpacked}].
+     current}].
```

Start a shell again and make it permanent:

```
1> application:start(sasl),
1> release_handler:make_permanent("1.0").
ok
```

[Note:  all that `make_permanent/1` does is put the release version (`"1.0"`) in `~/lib/erlang/releases/start_erl.data` so you could cheat here.]

Be sure to place your system configuration in `~/lib/erlang/releases/1.0/sys.config`.

Now when you run `~/bin/start` the release name will be read from `start_erl.data` and `init` will use the boot script in `~/lib/erlang/releases/1.0/start.boot`.